# How to retrive value of 17 textBox in an array Using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, textbox

I have Written the code below which is too long. I want some shorter code:

```
b[0]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox1").value);
b[1]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox4").value);
b[2]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox7").value);
b[3]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox10").value);
b[4]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox13").value);
b[5]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox16").value);
b[6]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox19").value);
b[7]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox22").value);
b[8]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox25").value);
b[9]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox28").value);
b[10]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox31").value);
b[11]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox34").value);
b[12]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox37").value);
b[13]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox40").value);
b[14]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox43").value);
b[15]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox46").value);
b[16]=parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox49").value);
```

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < 17; i += 1) {
    b[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox"+(i * 3 + 1)).value);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as the numbers of the text boxes appear to increase by 3 each time, a simple loop should do it:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 17; ++i) {
   b[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox" + (i * 3 + 1)).value);
}
```