# how to retrieve value of 17 selectbox in to array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

```
a[0]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select18").value);
a[1]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select19").value);
a[2]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select20").value);
a[3]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select21").value);
a[4]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select22").value);
a[5]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select23").value);
a[6]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select24").value);
a[7]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select25").value);
a[8]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select26").value);
a[9]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select27").value);
a[10]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select28").value);
a[11]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select29").value);
a[12]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select30").value);
a[13]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select31").value);
a[14]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select32").value);
a[15]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select33").value);
a[16]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("select34").value);
```

I have done it like this.
how to do it using loop? (small code please)

Comment: What have you tried, seems quite straight forward. Use a for-loop from 0 to 16, and have `a[i]` and `("select"+(i+18))`.

Comment: you asked *a very similar* question **and got a perfectly good answer which you accepted** an hour ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579113/how-to-retrive-value-of-17-textbox-in-an-array-using-javascript ..

Comment: @JaromandaX It's not exactly the same question, but the same concept applies. Looks like the OP needs to look into how for-loops work in general.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
var startNode=18;
var endNode=34;
var index=0;
var a=[];
for(var i=startNode;i<=endNode;i++){
  a.push(parseFloat(document.getElementById("select"+i).value));
}
```

Comment: thank you for for you answer

Comment: @jagdish you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

setting an id to each element - isn't good, try to set some class to tham, and make something like this:

```
var selects = document.geteElementsByClassName('selectClass'),
    i = 0, len = selects.length,
    a = [];

for (i; i < len; i++) {
    a.push(selects[i].value);
}
```